# The property could not be set to a 'null' value

Tags: devart

I updated to the latest version of Devart Entity Developer 6.3.569 today and the associated Salesforce .net connector. Now I am getting messages like this

The 'ForeclosureShortsaleDate' property on 'Account' could not be set to a 'null' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.

This is happening when I am pulling a record from the context. I have removed many fields from the model that have generated this error because I don't need them anyway but this is not ideal. Especially of the model needs to be recreated, Can anyone explain this to me? All of the columns in question have the Nullable property set to true.

Additional Info:
Template: DBContext

I can't say that the updated version is the issue because I don't know what the Salesforce team are doing in the Sandbox but this context worked properly last week by pulling and pushing data into the sandbox. Up until till this point there have been no model changes on my end. Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I created a clean and fresh model and I get the same results.

UPDATE: 
I believe it is indeed Devart Entity Developer. I checked the last version in version control and this is what the property looked like before version 6.3.569

```
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for BillingLatitude in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual global::System.Nullable<double> BillingLatitude
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

and what it looks like with 6.3.569

```
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for BillingLatitude in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual global::System.Double BillingLatitude
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

I'm going to revert to the last version and generate the model again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is version 6.3.569 of Entity Developer. The Model Generation is not working properly.

this is the results from 6.3.555

```
    /// <summary>
    /// There are no comments for BillingLatitude in the schema.
    /// </summary>
    public virtual global::System.Nullable<double> BillingLatitude
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```